# Laptop not charging during video playback

Tags: 18.04

My Alienware laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 will charge perfectly fine when the laptop is turned off. However, when the laptop is in Ubuntu itself, the following issues arise:

a) It will not charge straight away when the cable is plugged in. There is a delay and often the cable needs to be wiggled till it works. The port isn't the issue as I have tried other cables with no issue charging normally when the laptop is off.

b) Once it does start charging, charging can be interrupted just by moving the mouse or playing a YouTube video. This issue doesn't always occur, but happens more often than not.

c) video playback is choppy and will buffer often. As soon as the charging cable is remove, playback immediately improves.

I'm sure there is some driver issue but I'm unsure of how to proceed. Any advice would be helpful.